# ¿Cómo optimizar una función de reemplazar en PHP en AWS? Insuficiente memoria

Tags: php, php7, aws

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
private function convertToX(array $files)
{
    foreach($files as $file)
    {
        $rFile = fopen($file, 'r+');
        $data = fread($rFile, filesize($file));
        fclose($rFile);

        $find = '/""/i';
        $replace = 'X';
        $newData = preg_replace($find, $replace, $data);
        unset($data);
        $wFile = fopen($file, 'w');
        fwrite($wFile, $newData);
        fclose($wFile);
    }
}
```

Creo que falla en la línea `$newData = preg_replace($find, $replace, $data);` porque uno de los ficheros pesa `2.9 GB`, sin embargo, lo extraño es que mi instancia de AWS tiene 8GB, en teoría. Obviamente, el script está configurado para usar toda la memoria RAM disponible en el servidor `ini_set('memory_limit','-1');`

Error:

```
mmap() failed: [12] Cannot allocate memory
PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 5554503680)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

prueba con las funciones `file_get_contents` y `file_put_contents`

```php
private function convertToX(array $files)
{
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        if (!file_exists($file)) {
            // Manejar archivos que no existen si es necesario
            continue;
        }

        // Leer el contenido del archivo
        $data = file_get_contents($file);

        // Reemplazar las comillas dobles con 'X'
        $newData = preg_replace('/"/i', 'X', $data);
        
        // Escribir el nuevo contenido al archivo
        file_put_contents($file, $newData);
    }
}
```

El código que proporcioné anteriormente ya es bastante eficiente en términos de uso de memoria RAM, ya que utiliza funciones integradas de PHP (file_get_contents y file_put_contents) que gestionan internamente la lectura y escritura de archivos sin necesidad de cargar todo el contenido en memoria al mismo tiempo.

Sin embargo, si tus archivos son muy grandes y deseas optimizar aún más el uso de memoria, podrías considerar procesar el archivo línea por línea en lugar de cargar todo el contenido de una vez. Aquí hay una versión modificada que utiliza esta técnica:

```
function convertToX(array $files)
{
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        if (!file_exists($file)) {
            // Manejar archivos que no existen si es necesario
            continue;
        }

        // Abre el archivo para lectura
        $rFile = fopen($file, 'r');

        if ($rFile === false) {
            // Manejar error de apertura del archivo si es necesario
            continue;
        }

        // Abre el archivo para escritura
        $wFile = fopen($file . '_temp', 'w');

        if ($wFile === false) {
            fclose($rFile);
            // Manejar error de apertura del archivo si es necesario
            continue;
        }

        // Procesa el archivo línea por línea
        while (($line = fgets($rFile)) !== false) {
            // Reemplazar las comillas dobles con 'X'
            $newLine = preg_replace('/"/i', 'X', $line);

            // Escribe la nueva línea al archivo temporal
            fwrite($wFile, $newLine);
        }

        // Cierra los archivos
        fclose($rFile);
        fclose($wFile);

        // Reemplaza el archivo original con el temporal
        rename($file . '_temp', $file);
    }
}
```

Este enfoque lee y procesa el archivo línea por línea, lo que puede ser más eficiente para archivos grandes

Comment: Gracias! Hice algo similar a lo que propones como segunda opción. Acepto tu respuesta como la solución por el tiempo invertido en responderme. Muchas gracias.